# shell script is not working when it is called using cron scheduler

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have this sh script

```
SPTH="/home/db_backup/log/log_"$(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')".txt"
echo "===DUMP started at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')===" >> "$SPTH";
DBNAME="test"

PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE $DBNAME";
PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres -d $DBNAME -c "ALTER SCHEMA public RENAME TO public_old";
for entry in /home/SQL/*.*
do
    echo "$entry"
    SUBSTRING=$(echo $entry| cut -d'/' -f 4)
    #echo $SUBSTRING
    SCHEMA=$(echo $SUBSTRING| cut -d'.' -f 1)
    echo $SCHEMA
    echo "===================== CREATING public SCHEMA =====================" >> "$SPTH";
    PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres -d $DBNAME -c "Create Schema public";
    echo "===================== RESTORING DATA OF $SCHEMA =====================" >> "$SPTH";
    PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres -d $DBNAME -f "$entry";
    echo "===================== DELETING SCHEMA $SCHEMA=====================" >> "$SPTH";
    PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres -d $DBNAME -c "DROP SCHEMA $SCHEMA CASCADE";
    echo "===================== RENAMING SCHEMA PUBLIC TO $SCHEMA=====================" >> "$SPTH";
    PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres -d $DBNAME -c "ALTER SCHEMA public RENAME TO $SCHEMA";
    echo "===================== RENAMING SQL FILE =====================" >> "$SPTH";
    mv /home/SQL/{$SUBSTRING,DONE--$SUBSTRING};
    echo "===================== DONE =====================" >> "$SPTH";
done
PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -U postgres -d $DBNAME -c "ALTER SCHEMA public_old RENAME TO public";
echo "===DUMP finished at $(date +'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')===" >> "$SPTH";
```

When I am running this command using command

```
sh script.sh
```

its working fine, working as I expected and running each and every command. But when I am running this script using cron scheduler commands related to POSTGRES is not executing. I also want log of every command I in this shell script.

I want to run this script using cron scheduler.

Where I am wrong?

Comment: cron has not the same Environment as your user in the shell. I think this will be your problem

Comment: Oh! thanks. Can you suggest some better way to achieve what I want.

Comment: For the reason written by @Jens, try setting the absolute path of postgres command in your script, or setting PATH environment variable inside it.